# Oracle SQL Developer does not show the grids in the query result

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When executing a query on Oracle SQL Developer the result is text rather than a grid. I'd like it to display a grid, but I do not know how to display them.

[image: Query result]

Comment: You mean you want to run the statement with output to the result window (via green 'play' button, or control-enter); instead of running as a script with output to the worksheet (vis doc+play button or F5)? Or are you asking about the alignment within the script output window? Why aren't you using a fixed-width font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, which is "Run Script" command.
You need to press green triangle at the top, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Also F9 will do the same as CTRL-Enter